# iOS || Swift || how to convert date response String to expeced timestamp

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `date` object whose type is `String`, and the value from backend response will be `2022-8-01T03:23:35.430+0000`, how can I convert it to the expected format like `Mon, 1 Aug 2022, 3:23 pm`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , it tells you `
Search, and research` in **big bold** letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

```
let dateString = "2022-8-01T03:23:35.430+0000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

print(date) // Date object

/// Date to String

let format = "EEE, d MMM YYYY, h:ss a" // format you need as a String
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = format
//By default AM/PM symbols are uppercased
formatter.amSymbol = "am"
formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
let label: String = formatter.string(from: date!)

print(label) // "Mon, 1 Aug 2022, 3:23 pm"
```